# Mongo DB nested array $set to update document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, multidimensional-array, mongodb-query

this is my document
Please Let me know how to update
cart.sizeQuantity.quantity value
it should update the value where productId matches then check for size match and then update

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "email": "user@gmail.com",
  "password": "***************",
  "cart": [
    {
      "productId": "1253456912854",
      "sizeQuantity": [
        {
          "size": "Large",
          "quantity": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "productId": "1253456912855",
      "sizeQuantity": [
        {
          "size": "Large",
          "quantity": 2
        },
        {
          "size": "X-Large",
          "quantity": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "__v": 0
}
```

I have tried doing this But this didn't work

```
const hasSize = await this.findOne({
    _id: userId,
    "cart.productId": productId,
    "cart.sizeQuantity.size": productSize,
  });
  if (hasSize) {
await this.updateOne(
    {
      _id: userId,
      cart: { $elemMatch: { productId: productId } },
      "cart.sizeQuantity.size": productSize,
    },
    {
      $set: {
        "cart.$.sizeQuantity.quantity": 4,
      },
    }
  );

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain up arrayFilters to update your nested array element. See [official doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-nested-arrays-in-conjunction-with----) for more usage.

```js
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1,
  "cart.productId": "1253456912854",
  "cart.sizeQuantity.size": "Large"
},
{
  $set: {
    "cart.$[c].sizeQuantity.$[sq].quantity": 4
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "c.productId": "1253456912854"
    },
    {
      "sq.size": "Large"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HJxC3eCR4Oh)